# php mail() returning false, but not in command line

Tags: php, apache, email, ubuntu

I've been looking around on stackoverflow and many other websites for ideas, but nothing has worked so far and I need more direct help.

I have a dedicated Ubuntu Server (9.04 jaunty) and I'm running several PHP websites there, with apache2. My problem is that the mail() function has stopped working. Since a while back I've been using PEAR Mail Queue for most emails, so I'm not sure exactly when mail() stopped working, but I still need it for an OpenCart setup, among a few other things, but mail() keeps return false no matter what I do. Even this simple code won't work:

```
<?php
mail('mail@example.com','test','test');
?>
```

So, I've been looking at the Sendmail-settings in php.ini which all check out, and when I run this in the command line, it works fine and sends me an email:

```
# sendmail
mail@example.com
test message
```

So I thought it might be php itself that has a problem, so I try the following command:

```
# php -r "mail('mail@example.com','test','test');"
```

And it also sends the email without any problems! So what could it be? I started thinking it might be some sort of permission problem, that maybe www-data had some issues with running the script. Still not sure about this, because I can't even run this script:

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

It also returns false! I've run the **visudo** command and added the following line just in case:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

And I've changed the user and group owners of the files from **root:root** to **www-data:www-data** but still nothing!

What else can I try? There must be someting!  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the system-mail-error-log (/var/log/mail or something like that) while using mail when it fails?

Comment: Drop `mail()`. Use i.e. `PhpMailer` and make it deliver via `SMTP` and you are on safe ground.

Comment: There are alot of errors that say `SYSERR(UID0): Who are you?: Permission denied` and a few that complain about the submit.cf file on the line with RunAsUser and TrusedUser `unknown user smmsp: Permission denied` where smmsp is set on both. What should I do with this? @Louis

Answer (score 3):

Commandline and webserver don't share the same php.ini! Check which php.ini is used on commandline and in the server module.

Comment: Nevermind, found it. But the files are pretty much identical, that's not the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: try just to be on the safe side rename apache php.ini to php.ini.bak and copy the cli php.ini and check. It will narrow down your scope of issue to look into

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few weeks ago. I tried:

- [PHP mail() works from command line but not apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462941/php-mail-works-from-command-line-but-not-apache)
- [PHP "mail()" function sends mail from php5 cli but not when the script is run by a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608249/php-mail-function-sends-mail-from-php5-cli-but-not-when-the-script-is-run-by)

And a few others.

I had a entry in my **error log** saying `Segmentation fault`. After 2 days a found the problem. I used Exim4 on my debian system, the combination with apache2 gave a segmentation fault. I replaced Exim4 with Postfix and it worked!

However, in your case you cannot run a exec like `whoami` and you should pursuit that path.

Because the mail function eventually comes to the os, a exec command should work!

Comment: Then what do you suggest I do about it? What in php controls this kind of permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You could send email using phpMailer throw SMTP with out using you mail() function.
The code is [here(http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
Just a idea

possibly can use this [extation](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3932) for opencart to use phpmailer to replace mail function. I have not tested this just so it and thought it might give someone some ideas.

Comment: Well no, OpenCart uses the mail()-function so I need it to work, unfortunately. Otherwise I wouldn't bother with this so much.

Comment: I updated my answer it looks like someone has made a extation for open cart to use phpmailer This may not help you but it could help someone that don't have as much access to there server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `php-fpm` used in Magento docker image I was playing with. It kept php preloaded (with configuration).

After restarting it picked up new settings: [how to restart](https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm) or just `sudo killall php-fpm`.