# call codeigniter URL using curl command linux

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, curl, amazon-ec2

I have a web site in codeigniter. I have created some cronjob url's , now i am trying to hit those url from my Linux server. but it is not working. 
URL is as below

> ```
> curl https://www.sampletest.com/samnet/admin/panel/cronjobs/transaction
> ```

This url basically return nothing. and sends email notification.
If i hit this url from webbrowser it works properly. and send notification mail. 
I need to call this url in cron. No idea what should i do in this case. 
Please help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mail() returning false, but not in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372542/php-mail-returning-false-but-not-in-command-line)

Comment: What error did you get in bash?

Comment: You want to set a cronjob to this URL. Is it?

Comment: yes i want to set it in cron, but it is not working manually . then how it will work in cron. can u tell me which option i should try in wget.

Comment: @zod - but it is working fine from web browser.

Comment: Have you followed [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html)?

Comment: @Tpojka - i didn't follow that doc, Can we not execute codeigniter urls from curl or wget command

Comment: Do you want to set cron job or access url from other server (those are different issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* * * * * wget -O - http://yoursite.com/tasks.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I believe this should work for you. You can setup your cronjob according to your requirement.

Naturally, you can hit this URL something like this

```
wget http://website.com/files/file.zip
```